# Removing white space from field values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, field-calculator, python-parser

If I have a field say 'account' and I want all the white space (if there is any to the right and left of the account entry, for example 83128313 - is there a python script or field calculator function that can do this for me?

Comment: You want to count them or remove them?

Comment: This has already been answered on [SO] - See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8270146/5754917

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for the [str.strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) method:

Calculate your field to be:

```
!account!.strip()
```

This will remove all the whitespaces both to the left and to the right.

Having this:

`s = '   83128313  '`

would result after:

`s.strip()`

in

`'83128313'`

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for this I am running this now, on 80000 records it seems to take along time, should this be instant, or will it 'churn' alittle?

Comment: it depends a bit on the hard disk you have. On an average professional laptop, running this on the 80,000 rows wouldn't take more than 10-20 secs top. On mine, with SSD disk, it took just about 5 secs. I believe running this in the editing session would take longer time, too.

Answer (score -1):

With ArcPy you would do the following:

```
import arcpy

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(r'pathToYourDataset',['theField']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = row[0].strip()
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

All you have to do is replace *theField* with the name of the field you want to update, and *pathToYourDataset* with the path to your dataset, such as:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(r"D:\PythonTesting\randomData\City.shp",['spatialID']) as cursor:
```

Comment: please fix the syntax error - the cursor takes the `fc` first and then the `fields`.

Comment: This won't work - your `updatecursor` is set up wrong

Comment: True, I wrote it from memory and got the parameters mixed up. You could have edited it yourself to provide faster help :-)